# Given a HANDLE, is it possible to list OVERLAPPED requests?

Tags: c, winapi

Given a HANDLE, is it possible to get any of the following:

- OVERLAPPED structures for that handle
- The buffers used for those reads/writes
- The names of files/pipes used in those reads/writes

Comment: Most of this information is not available from user mode. You can - however - get the file name calling [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953.aspx) with a `FileNameInfo` parameter.

Comment: That's too bad. So does that mean that I need to keep track of all OVERLAPPED requests and their corresponding buffers myself?